# PHP, relacionamento Muito para Muitos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-7

Minha dúvida é na construção da Lógica.

Como faço, para que determino item, possa ter mais de um valor?

EX: Tenho a tabela de Veiculos e a tabela de Insumos.
Cada veiculo, pode ter mais de um tipo de insumo( Gasolina, Alcool )

No momento, a tabela veículos está apenas com um insumo:

ID----- VEICULO---INSUMO

01------HHR000----GASOLINA.

Cheguei a pensar em colocar uma coluna p cada insumo, mas gostaria de algo mais pratico. Desse jeito:

ID----- VEICULO---INSUMO

01------HHR000----GASOLINA / ETANOL / OLEO LUBRIFICANTE.

Não to sabendo fazer.

Agradeço qq ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Se você está utilizando um banco de dados relacional, não é possível utilizar atributos multivalorados, e a solução que você pensou realmente não é a mais prática. Em bancos de dados relacionais, para lidar com situações como essa, são criadas tabelas chamadas, na teoria, de **entidades fracas**.

No seu caso, você teria que criar uma terceira tabela (chamemos de VeiculoInsumo - geralmente o nome das entidades fracas são formados pelo nome das tabelas que deram origem a ela), cuja chave primária seria formada pela chave primária da tabela de veículos e da tabela de insumos, ou seja, pelo campo *ID* das duas tabelas.

Nas suas consultas e operações no banco, se você quisesse obter ou realizar instruções sobre os dados dessa relação N:N, você teria que considerar essa nova tabela criada.

Num exemplo prático, a tabela *VeiculoInsumo* ficaria (mudei o nome do atributo *ID* das duas outras tabelas na nova tabela para não ficar confuso):

ID_VEICULO--- ID_INSUMO

01        --- 01

01        --- 02

Considerando que na tabela de insumos o *ID* 01 corresponde a gasolina e 02 a álcool, os dados acima indicam que o veículo de *ID* 01 usa tanto gasolina quanto álcool.

Usando essa solução, você pode simular a utilização de atributos multivalorados em bancos de dados relacionais.

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Agora consigo entender melhor. Mas nesse caso, como tem que ser inserido os dados na tabela VeiculoInsumo? Na pagina de cadastro, terei que criar uma pagina de cadastro p veiculos e informar os ids dos insumos?   Tipo, ID_carro, Modelo tal, nos insumos seria 1,2,1,1?? Pq, se for nesse lógica, n seria o msm que informar direto o nome do insumo?  Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Ou eu teria que inserir  dados 2 vezes ao msm temp no Banco? Uma vez na tabela veiculos, com as informações do veiculos, ao msm tempo que insiro os dados 1,2,3 na tabela Veiculos_Insumos?

Comment: Seria mais ou menos o que você escreveu no segundo comentário. O que se faria geralmente no seu caso é: no cadastro de veículos, haveria uma opção (como um select que permite selecionar múltiplas opções - v. https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select_multiple) para que o usuário selecionasse os insumos que o veículo utiliza. No código que registrar os dados no banco, você insere primeiro os dados do veículo e, com o novo ID do veículo cadastrado que foi gerado no banco, você insere na tabela VeiculoInsumo as linhas com os insumos selecionados, com o ID do Veiculo (+)

Comment: E os IDs dos insumos selecionados pelo usuário.